# Leibniz's notation for geometric derivative (product calculus)

Tags: calculus, notation

The *[geometric integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral#Type_II:_geometric_integral)* (aka product or multiplicative integral) is defined as:

$$\prod_{a}^{b}f(x)^{\mathrm{d}x}=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\prod {f(x_{i})^{\Delta x}}=\exp \left(\int_{a}^{b}\ln f(x) \mathrm{d}x\right)$$

The inverse operation, the *geometric derivative*, is sometimes denoted with an asterisk à la Lagrange's notation, for example in the fundamental theorem of geometric calculus:

$$\prod_{a}^{b}f^{*}(x)^{\mathrm{d}x}={\frac {f(b)}{f(a)}}$$

Now, what is the Leibnizian notation for the geometric derivative?  Given that Leibniz's notation for the ordinary (additive) derivative,

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} \quad\rightarrow\quad \int_a^b \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x=f(b)-f(a),$$

is reminiscent of the limit definition and involves the inverse of the additive integral's product (i.e., $f(x)\mathrm{d}x$), I assumed

$$\sqrt[\mathrm{d}x\enspace]{\mathrm{d}f} \quad\rightarrow\quad \prod_{a}^{b} \left(\sqrt[\mathrm{d}x\enspace]{\mathrm{d}f}\right)^{\mathrm{d}x}={\frac {f(b)}{f(a)}}$$

which seemed like the analogous inverse of $f(x)^{\mathrm{d}x}$. Is this correct? Or acceptable in the absence of a prevailing convention?

Comment: Your notation seems to imply that $\Pi_a^b \mathrm d f = f(a)/f(b)$, which is not what you want ...